# PL/SQL Procedure for a Table Column that contains SQL statement strings

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am tasked with building a procedure that inserts values into a new table based on the values from another, including a column that contains strings that are different SELECT statements.

The table I'm working with has an `ID` column, and a `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` column, and a `SRC_CODE` column which contains, for ex. `(SELECT KEY FROM FACT_TABLE WHERE DAY_ID = V_DAY_ID AND some other condition)`. So this procedure must populate the V_DAY_ID variable before being executed. The values that will be inserted into the new table will be the values from `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` columns, and the associated `KEY`s (thousands of results) coming from the select statement in the `SRC_CODE` column. I'm a novice when it comes to PL/SQL, so I'm a bit lost building this procedure.

Here's what I've put together, even though it's not correct, it should give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE METRICS (DAY_ID IN NUMBER)
IS
    CURSOR CUR_ITEMS IS
        SELECT ID, ITEM1, ITEM2 FROM METRICSTABLE;

    CURSOR CUR_SRC_CODE IS
        SELECT ID, SRC_CODE FROM METRICSTABLE;

    VDAY_ID NUMBER;
    V_KEY INTEGER;

BEGIN
VDAY_ID := DAY_ID;


FOR i IN CUR_SRC_CODE LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SRC_CODE INTO V_KEY;
END LOOP;    

FOR REC IN CUR_ITEM LOOP
    INSERT INTO KEY_METRICS (KEY, ITEM1, ITEM2, CRE_DT) 
                                  VALUES (V_KEY, ITEM1, ITEM2, SYSDATE);
    COMMIT;
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Go read up on the execute immediate with the "using" clause to pass in a parameter value.

Comment: No need for a cursor: `insert into key_metrics (key, item1, item2, cre_dt) select ...` will be **much** more efficient. Also you are throwing way all results from the `CUR_SRC_CODE` cursor except for the last one. I'm pretty sure that's not what you wan either.

Comment: I appreciate the input. How do I handle the result set from the `execute immediate SRC_CODE` in an insert into select statement? I have thousands of keys resulting from that `SRC_CODE` select statement string and they need to be tied to the `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` values that are in row with the `SRC_CODE` column.

Comment: How you want to store the result in `V_KEY`, comma separated values? (e.g. `ID, SRC_CODE,ID, SRC_CODE,ID, SRC_CODE, .... etc`).

Comment: The reason I thought a cursor would be the best bet is so I could just pull each individual `KEY` from the execution of the `SRC_CODE` statement as it looped through, attach the corresponding `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` values, and then insert the record into the target table. Could this not work with a nested loop?

Answer (score 0):

This did exactly what I wanted it to do, thanks all for the tips:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE POPULATETARGET IS   
    TYPE KEYS_T IS TABLE OF SOMETABLE.KEY%TYPE;
    L_KEYS KEYS_T;
    V_DAY NUMBER;
    V_SRC_CODE VARCHAR2 (4000);
    RC SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    V_DAY := 20150826;

OPEN RC FOR SELECT SRC_CODE FROM SOURCE;
LOOP
    FETCH RC INTO V_SRC_CODE;
    EXIT WHEN RC%NOTFOUND;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SRC_CODE BULK COLLECT INTO L_KEYS USING V_DAY;
        FORALL x IN L_KEYS.FIRST..L_KEYS.LAST
            INSERT INTO TARGET (KEY, ITEM1, ITEM2) 
            VALUES((L_KEYS(x)), (SELECT ITEM1 FROM SOURCETBL WHERE SRC_CODE = V_SRC_CODE), (SELECT ITEM2 FROM SOURCETBL WHERE SRC_CODE = V_SRC_CODE));
            COMMIT;
END LOOP;
CLOSE RC;   
END;
```